# Apex Trigger to auto increment a number field based on another field change value

Tags: apex, trigger

Hello I will be glad if anyone can help me. I created two custom number fields on the Lead Object. as below:

```
SQL_Counter__c
MQL_Counter__C
```

I am trying to write a trigger that will increase any of these counters whenever Lead Status changes as follows:

```
If Lead Status == 'Open SQL' then increment SQL_Counter__c by 1  
If Lead Status == 'Open MQL' then increment MQL_Counter__c by 1
```

My I compile, I do not get any error, but when I edit a Lead record, the fields does not change. Please help review the code.

```
trigger updateLeadStatusChangeCounter on Lead (after insert, before update) {
    for(Lead l : Trigger.new)
    try{
        if (l.Status!=Null){

        if (l.Status =='Open SQL'){

            l.SQL_Counter__c +=1;
        }
        else if (l.Status =='Open MQL'){

            l.MQL_Counter__c +=1;
        }

    }
    }
     catch (System.NullPointerException e)
     {

     }

}
```

Comment: When I compile, I do not get any errors, but the trigger is not updating the Counter fields

Comment: instead `after insert` use `before insert`

Comment: @Ratan I tried that but still no success

Comment: `l.SQL_Counter__c +=1;` instead use `l.SQL_Counter__c = l.SQL_Counter__c  != null ? l.SQL_Counter__c +1: 0;`

Comment: @Ratan, You are a star! this works, thank you very much..

Comment: Most welcome ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution is** .... Basically you used try catch so you are not getting error

Issue in your field `l.SQL_Counter__c` is null that was the reason....

```
trigger updateLeadStatusChangeCounter on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    for(Lead l : Trigger.new){

        if (l.Status =='Open SQL'){
            l.SQL_Counter__c = l.SQL_Counter__c != null ? l.SQL_Counter__c +1: 1;
        }
        else if (l.Status =='Open MQL'){
            l.MQL_Counter__c = l.MQL_Counter__c != null ? l.MQL_Counter__c + 1: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need on more help to get a 100% code coverage, My test class is giving me only 63%, I don't know what I am doing wrong.                                                   private class updateLeadStatusChangeCounter { 
 @isTest static void UpdateCounter() {

  Lead l = new Lead();
  l.FirstName = 'Jack';
  l.LastName = 'Daniels';
  l.Status = 'Open';
  l.Company = 'Snow White Consulting';
  l.LeadSource = 'Event';
  insert l;

  l.Company = 'Snow Global Consulting';
  l.Status = 'Prospect';
  update l;

  
 }
 
 
 
}

Comment: @user3722925 pls ask a new question with you trigger and test class.. I will take a look into your issue

Comment: @user3722925 try this `private class updateLeadStatusChangeCounter { 

  @isTest static void UpdateCounter() { 
    Lead l = new Lead(); 
 l.FirstName = 'Jack'; 
 l.LastName = 'Daniels'; 
 l.Status = 'Open SQL'; 
 l.Company = 'Snow White Consulting'; 
 l.LeadSource = 'Event'; 
 insert l; 
 system.assertEquals([SELECT SQL_Counter__c  FROM Lead WHERE Id =: l.Id ].SQL_Counter__c, 1);
 l.Company = 'Snow Global Consulting'; 
 l.Status = 'Open MQL'; 
 update l; 
 system.assertEquals([SELECT MQL_Counter__c   FROM Lead WHERE Id =: l.Id ].MQL_Counter__c , 1);
   } 
}`

Comment: Wow! it works again... 100% coverage! you are really a star! thank you very much.

Comment: not sure why I got downvote. If I am doing anything wrong pls let me know I will correct that..  :-)

Comment: I don't know how you got a down vote as this is not from me, you answered everything I asked correctly.

Comment: @user3722925 not sure who did... No problem .. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35972/discussion-between-user3722925-and-ratan).

Comment: I discovered some bug on the code. 1. when the Status change to either Open SQL or Open MQL, the Counter first changes to 0. I want it to start from 1 instead of 0. 2. Each time a lead record gets updated, the counters keep increasing by one even when the status does not change. I want it to only increase if there is a status change to either Open MQL or Open SQL. If it is on Open SQL or Open MQL and the record is updated, there should be no counter increment. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this should work in before insert trigger, Added braces in line three and second last line. Also make sure that the default values are there in `MQL_Counter__c` and `SQL_Counter__c`. You may want to mark default as zero.

```
trigger updateLeadStatusChangeCounter on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    for(Lead l : Trigger.new){ //ADD Start Bracket Here
    try{
        if (l.Status!=Null){

        if (l.Status =='Open SQL'){

            l.SQL_Counter__c +=1;
        }
        else if (l.Status =='Open MQL'){

            l.MQL_Counter__c +=1;
        }

    }
    }
     catch (System.NullPointerException e)
     {

     }
}//Add this Here
}
```

**UPDATE**

First try doing without using try catch block. That will help you to uncover any issues masked by exception handling.

Modified Code without try catch

```
trigger updateLeadStatusChangeCounter on Lead (before insert, before update) {
        for(Lead l : Trigger.new){ //ADD Start Bracket Here
        //try{ Commented
            if (l.Status!=Null){

            if (l.Status =='Open SQL'){

                l.SQL_Counter__c +=1;
            }
            else if (l.Status =='Open MQL'){

                l.MQL_Counter__c +=1;
            }

        }
        /*}Commented
         catch (System.NullPointerException e)
         {

         }*/
    }//Add this Here
    }
```

Comment: Without the try and catch, I was having 'Attempt to dereference a null object' errors which even made it worst